# need help on google map api for MapTypeControl (Satellite-MapMaker)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to achieve the red marked functionality given in the map1, I called the google map API code, its working but as per our design the functionality and Satellite, Traffic tab is not appearing with image(satellite). please refer map1.jpg

Because if you go to the  Google map, in that you can see the Satellite and Traffic in the right top side, so the same functionality is required in our design. I was searching and trying to find the solution but I did not get that, so please can you help me on this it will be very grateful.

Please refer Map2.jpg which i achieved currently.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Viji (vijijobmail@gmail.com)![Map1-exact functionality required][1]![Map2- which i am getting currently][2]

Comment: Where are the images you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Setting your map type id to satellite or hybrid can solve your problem.This can be done in following ways:

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
```

or

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
```

Also add this code:

```
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

For more help go to following links:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers